# wi-fi adapter not found 22.04

Tags: make

I brought a new laptop and wifi adapter was not found so did some research and got a solution that
Now that you have installed the prerequisites successfully by tethering, let's install the driver. It can all be done from the terminal!

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Your wireless should now be working.

But after running make and sudo make install getting error

```
 make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/build M=/home/hexa-l27/rtw89 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-43-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  CC [M]  /home/hexa-l27/rtw89/core.o
In file included from /home/hexa-l27/rtw89/core.c:13:
/home/hexa-l27/rtw89/fw.h:3214:17: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘DECLARE_FLEX_ARRAY’
 3214 |                 DECLARE_FLEX_ARRAY(u8, raw);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:285: /home/hexa-l27/rtw89/core.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1875: /home/hexa-l27/rtw89] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-43-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2

:~/rtw89$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/build M=/home/hexa-l27/rtw89 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-43-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  CC [M]  /home/hexa-l27/rtw89/core.o
In file included from /home/hexa-l27/rtw89/core.c:13:
/home/hexa-l27/rtw89/fw.h:3214:17: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘DECLARE_FLEX_ARRAY’
 3214 |                 DECLARE_FLEX_ARRAY(u8, raw);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:285: /home/hexa-l27/rtw89/core.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1875: /home/hexa-l27/rtw89] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-43-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

thank you